# How to filter The rows in datagridview by cell value in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, filter

I have a datagridview in a form that has 5 cells 
i want to filter rows in some condition  which is the 5th Cell value isn't 0

I tried the following code but it didn't work correctly

```
 for (int i = 0; i < frm.dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (frm.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString() == "0")
            {

                CurrencyManager currencyManager1 = (CurrencyManager)dataGridView1.BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource];
                currencyManager1.SuspendBinding();
               dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = false;
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                currencyManager1.ResumeBinding();

            }
            else
            {

               dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = true;

            }
        }
```

The stored procedure i use for receiving data

```
    @Criterion varchar(30)
as

SELECT [id] as 
      ,[car_num] 
      ,[customer]
      ,[driver]
      ,[first]
      ,[second] 
      ,[sum] 
      ,[price] 
      ,[date1]
      ,[date2] 
      ,[city] 
      ,[type] 


  FROM [dbo].[Data]


  where 
  [car_num]+
  [customer]+
  [driver]+
 convert (varchar, [first])+
 convert (varchar, [second])+
 convert (varchar, [sum])+
 convert (varchar, [price])
like '%' + @Criterion +'%'
```

Comment: The best general way to filter DataGridViews I know of is to a) keep your data in DataTable, 2) make a DataView object and set DataSource of the DataView to DataTable. 3) Set DataGridView DataSource to DataView. After that, you can use DataView object's RowFilter property as sort of ersatz sql filter. Minimal amount of code required and it's almost certainly faster than anything you can come up with on your own.

Comment: @AvoNappo I  manged to to this by the code:
   dataView1.RowFilter = "second='0'"; but this shows the rows that contains 0 , how can i do the opposite ?

Answer (score 3):

Try below code and look into comments for details.

```
            //USE A FOREACH, YOU DO NOT NEED WORRY ABOUT INDEXS (WHICH CAUSES PROBLEMS MANY TIMES)
            foreach (DataGridViewRow rowItem in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                //CHECK FOR OBJECT EXISTENCE BEFORE DOING ANYTHING
                //AVOID ACCESSING CELL VALUE WITH INDEX. GO WITH COLUMN NAME. NO ISSUES IF COLUMNS ARE ALTERED LATER POINT.
                if (rowItem.Cells["number"].Value != null)
                {
                    //CHECK THE VALUE AND SET VISISBLE/INVISIBLE
                    if (rowItem.Cells["number"].Value.ToString() == "0")
                        rowItem.Visible = false;
                    else
                        rowItem.Visible = true;
                }
            }
```

Comment: I tried it but no effect , I'm using a stored procedure as a data source, can it be the reason for the problem ?

Comment: Is it possible for you to filter the rows in stored procedure it self?

Comment: yes , it's possible but I have few experience with it

Comment: ok. can you do one more try? Do this before for each. CurrencyManager currencyManager1 = (CurrencyManager)dataGridView1.BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource];
                currencyManager1.SuspendBinding();

Comment: It didn't work , i think the solution will be in the stored procedure, I edited the post with the stored procedure